# Rails REST API design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

i want to create a "messenger" and i have those models:

- Account
- Message
- Message channel

Account has many channels, Channel has many messages, message belongs to account(sender)
Also - there is an access restrictions to control which users can read/write to channel
Question is - how to create beautiful routes(and controller methods) to manage theese models..

Sorry for my bad english.(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use nested ressourcs! In `config/routes.rb`

```
ressources :accounts do
  ressources :message_channels do
    ressources :messages
  end
end
```

This will automaticly generate RESTfull URLs but you have to update all the views because of the changed _path methods. You can view the paths by calling `rake routes`.

Comment: I believe it should be resources and not singular resource.